# Turn off Single -Sign-On during debugging

Tags: authentication, azure, azure-active-directory

I was wondering whether its possible to turn off Single-Sign for my MVC project during the debug mode and turn it on when we publish the website ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without Auth you won't be able to exercise many scenarios in your app while development. Assuming from your tag that this is an Azure AD integrated app, you could add a localhost reply URL to the application in Azure AD and enable SSO in dev mode as well as prod mode.

If instead you're sick of typing the credentials again and again, I recommend roboform :).

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just need to comment "Deny users" in web.config

```
<system.web>
<authentication mode="None" />
<authorization>
  <!--<deny users="?" />-->
</authorization>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" requestValidationMode="4.5" />
</system.web>
```